# which upanishad is this shloka from ? Iti cha 'pahatapāpmādasya cha guṇā na bhūtakāśe sambhavanti jīvā saṅkāpi nivaritā

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras, upanishads, reference-request

I am trying to find the upanishad from which this shloka occurs:

> Iti cha 'pahatapāpmādasya cha guṇā na bhūtakāśe sambhavanti jīvā saṅkāpi nivaritā

इति च ऽपहतपाप्मादस्य  च गुणा न भूतकाशे सम्भवन्ति जीवा संकापि निवरतिता

```
इति च (iti cha): And thus
अपहतपाप्मा (apahatapāpmā): One whose sins have been destroyed
अदस्य (adasya): Of that person
च (cha): And
गुणाः (guṇāḥ): Qualities, virtues
न (na): Not
भूतकाशे (bhūtakāśe): In the space of the physical elements
सम्भवन्ति (sambhavanti): Originate, arise
जीवा (jīvā): Souls, living beings
सङ्कापि (saṅkāpi): Even a little
निवरिता (nivaritā): Prevented, restrained
```

Based on some of the terms like **ऽपहतपाप्मा** it sounds like its from chāndogyopaniṣad but I couldn't find any shloka matching their.

any suggestions is appreciated.